# Access VBA - Help designing a Join form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a JoinTable, Table1 and Table2. Here is design (example):

```
JoinTable:
IDx
IDy

Table1:
IDx
Names
Surnames

Table2:
IDy
Address
City
```

Now, I will create a form, which will have a Recordsource of JoinTable. In this form I will have 2 combobox-es, from which I will select records from Table1 or Table2. Based on combobox selection (that's IDx or IDy), I want to see field values from related table....Example:

If I select from combobox IDx, I want to see in continuos form field values from Table2 under same record (which are joined in JoinTable).

I have managed to do this with subforms, but I have a lot of records that are joined in JoinTable under same ID's, so listing through subforms is not nice when there is a lot of matches, because subform's don't maximize when form is maximized (I tried this too with Iszoommed API, but It's still not good - screen flashes because of scrollbars appearing/dissapearing).

Does anybody have any idea on how I could navigate through records of both tables within same form, and without subforms so that I can maximize form and see all related records easily ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved It. What you must do is a little hard to explain, but in general:

1. When you create a form that has recordsource from JoinTable - you have to build a recordsource query that contains both ID's from your JoinTable and then all other fields from related tables that you desire to have a look to.
2. On this form you add fields from those 2 tables that are linked in JoinTable. If desired you can hide/unhide those fields based on what search you would like to do (via combobox for each table or something else).
3. Then you have to VBA code It, my solution is like this - I have put 2 option buttons on form. When one of them is selected, a combobox is shown and fields from table that will be searched (other combobox and fields from other table are hidden at that time). Code goes something like this (for upper example):

   Dim SQL As String

   ```
         SQL = "SELECT JoinTable.IDx, JoinTable.IDy, Table1.Names, Table1.Surnames" & _
             " FROM Table1 INNER JOIN JoinTable ON Table1.[IDx] = JoinTable.[IDx] " & _
               " WHERE JoinTable.IDx=" & Me.MyCombo

         If IsNull(MyCombo) = True Then

             Me.RecordSource = ""

         Else

             Me.RecordSource = SQL

         End If
   ```
4. Put this code in Combobox_After_Update and in Click_Event of Option buttons, and that's It. Now you can navigate through related (joined) records within one form with fields from related tables, using ID's of JoinTable and related tables and without subforms so you can maximize your form as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You do this in Access using sub-forms.
As for design issues, you could maybe use [other code](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-access/how-to-automatically-resize-a-forms-subform/33e30e46-3d58-4270-b130-101e30088239?auth=1) (I found some nice ideas googling *ms access subform auto resize*), but the flashes would probably stay there: Access, as all Office applications, does not support multi-threading, OS will have to halt GUI process in order to allow other processes run, and user sees 'flashes'.

Comment: I suggest you post a question on these flashes, and see what comes up. Because if not use a sub form, why do it in Access?...

Comment: Thanks for response @marlan, but actually I have solved It, without using subforms. It's a procedure with of a lot design problems to solve and some VBA coding, but It works. If I could post an example here I would show It.